# Combine Two Queries Mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to combine two queries.

```
$query_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1_results` WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
while($table1_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_1)){
    $total[] = $table1_results;
}
```

and

```
$query_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2_results` WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
while($table2_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_1)){
    $total[] = $table2_results;
}
```

> everything remains the same, just I want to combine two different
>   tables
>
> **table2_results**
>
> and
>
> **table2_results** in one query

I consulted a lot of examples, but did not get the desired result, please give an example proper solution to the problem
thank you

Comment: do they have any relation to each other

Comment: @AmanRawat It must be a query that joins two different tables

Comment: While you're at it, make sure you fix that SQL-injection vulnerability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an inner join

```
  SELECT * FROM `table1_results`  as a
  Inner join `table2_results` as b on a.id = b.id 
  WHERE a.id=".$_GET['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about select multiple tables?

```
Select * from `table1_results` as t1, `table2_results` as t2
where t1.id = $_GET['id'] OR t2.id = $_GET['id']
```